# не могу удалить данные при нажатии на кнопку из api json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Мне нужно удалить комментарий со страницы, используя ID комментария.
Здесь у меня идет получение данных(считаю большим минусов вывода данных через js но по другому не смог, так как я новичек в сравненнии с вами.), далее идет Удаление по клику, и в конце идет функция на добавление по клику.

После клика на кнопку выдает данное сообщение[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите разобраться - может я где-то, что то упустил?
И если есть такая возможность - то как избежать html разметки внутри js файла?

```
$('document').ready(function(){

 $.ajax({
    url: '*****',
    type: 'GET',
    dateType: 'json',
    data: {
        _method: 'GET'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // console.log("Count of data items: ", data.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // console.log( data[i].children.created_at);
            let $block = $(`
        <div class="container" id="comments-block">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1 offset-lg-1">
                <div class="profile-photo">
                    <img class="profile-img"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <span class="pname text-muted"></span>
              <span class="pdate text-muted"></span> 
              <br>
              <div class="content"></div>
              <ul class="list-inline d-flex text-muted">
                <li><span><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></span>Edit</li>
                <li><button id="delete"><span><i class="fas fa-times pl-3"></i></span>Delete</li>
                <li><span><i class="fas fa-reply pl-3"></i></span>Replay</button></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="all-simple-content"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
`);

            $block.find(".pname").text(data[i].author.name);
            $block.find(".profile-img").attr('src', data[i].author.avatar);
            $block.find(".pdate").text(data[i].author.created_at);
            $block.find(".content").text(data[i].content);
            $(".all-content").append($block);

            for (let n = 0; n < data[i].children.length; n++) {
                let $simpleBlock = $(`
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-1 offset-lg-2">
                <img class="profile-img-children" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-9">
                <span class="pname-children text-muted"></span>

                <span class="pdate-children text-muted"></span>
                <br>
                <div class="content-children"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
`);
                if (data[i].children[n] == undefined) {
                    return false;
                }

                $simpleBlock.find(".content-children").text(data[i].children[n].content);
                $simpleBlock.find(".pdate-children").text( data[i].children[n].created_at );
                $simpleBlock.find(".profile-img-children").attr('src', data[i].children[n].author.avatar);
                $simpleBlock.find(".pname-children").text(data[i].children[n].author.name);
                $block.find(".all-simple-content").append($simpleBlock);
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
$("#delete").click(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
  };
  var d = $(data[i]);
  $.ajax({
    url: `****/${d.Number('id')}`,
    type: 'POST',
    dateType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
        "_method": 'DELETE'
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
});

}
});

$("#send").click(function(data) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '*****',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      "content": $("#post-comments").val(),
      "parent": null
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
});

});
```

Comment: Что вы хотели сказать этой строчкой `url: ****/${d.Number('id')}`?

Comment: id комментария - я так понимаю, совсем не в ту степь ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Совет дня: Не создавайте на странице элементы с одинаковыми `id`.*

---

```
`...
<li><button class="delete"><span><i class="fas fa-times pl-3"></i></span>Delete</button></li>
...`

...
$block.find(".delete").data("id", data[i].id);
$(".all-content").append($block);


// прямо в $(document).ready(function(){ ... }), a не в другом обработчике:
$(".all-content").on("click", "button.delete", function(){
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: `****/${id}`,
    type: 'POST',
    dateType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
        "_method": 'DELETE'
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      // и здесь, видимо, надо удалить блок из DOM
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: POST  400 (Bad Request)
Failed to load  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Зачем Вы мне это пишите? Это совершенно другой вопрос.